# How can i use Token from an ERC20 Contract in my own contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereumjs

I have following contract here on ropsten
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x813870feba76f27ec1afcf79432e065a4839f7ab#code

I want to use tokens from a different erc20 contract(0x8eB24319393716668D768dCEC29356ae9CfFe285) inside my own contract.

I know that i have to approve the amount i want to use in my own contract from the Token contract those tokens i want to use in my contract (0x8eB24319393716668D768dCEC29356ae9CfFe285).

What i did
In remix i compiled the code and selected TOKEN from inside my contract,
i deployed TOKEN "at address" of 0x8eb24319393716668d768dcec29356ae9cffe285

i than approved this address 0x813870feba76f27ec1AfcF79432e065A4839F7(my contract)

and set amount to approve to 2
Which all worked.
[image]

But when i try to use the buy Function from inside my code- the transaction fails.

How can i use Token from a different erc20 Contract in my Contract?

Comment: Now how exactly does the title of your question represent anything of what you're asking in the body of your question???

Comment: its only 1 half of the question iits not working i still cant use the buy function- the whole thing is only finished when those 2 contracts work together

Comment: i obviously messed something up thatswhy im asking how to do this the proper way

Comment: @goodvibration already changed it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So taking a look at the events on etherscan, it looks like Approval events have been submitted to approve the transfer of 2 tokens from

`0x62f28320f688a7a4e0021c55d7ffd1acd770a133` (your wallet?)

to

`0x813870feba76f27ec1afcf79432e065a4839f7ab` (your contract)

[image]

However I wrote a small contract to check the balances and allowances in the ERC20 contract you are working with. The balance of your wallet `0x62f28320f688a7a4e0021c55d7ffd1acd770a133` in this ERC20 token contract is 0. I believe this is why the transfer is failing. You've approved the transfer of tokens to your contract, but the address you are trying to transfer tokens from does not have any.

[image]

---

**Updating With Comment Answers**

Additionally, the msg.sender in the buy function needed to be listed as an ambassador.

Comment: You can see on etherescn that i have 10 AGI in my wallet
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x62f28320f688a7a4e0021c55d7ffd1acd770a133
But you are correct when i check my metamsk account it says 0 agi

Comment: Yes, but the address of AGI is `0xb97e9bbb6fd49865709d3f1576e8506ad640a13b` not `0x8eB24319393716668D768dCEC29356ae9CfFe285 ` the address your are interacting with when you create your erc20 contract and try to make the transfer

Comment: i tried the same steps with this address 0xb97e9bbb6fd49865709d3f1576e8506ad640a13b
and its also not working

Comment: the transfer function works but i still cant use the buyfunction

Comment: Ok - so some progress - initially the address we were using was the mainnet AGI contract. Now for the `buy` function. I didn't realize how much code was getting called in the `purchaseTokens` which is included in the `buy` function. I'd try to update your `buy` function to return bool and only return the result of `checkAnd Transfer`. If this returns true, then you can conclude the interaction with the AGI contract is working correctly and there is a bug somewhere in `purchaseTokens`.

Comment: the tranasction(approve) to the agi contract go through, but the buy calls to my contract fail.
how can i update my buy function- i would have to redeploy  the contract?

Comment: looks like i figuered it out, the mistake was that i didnt add my address to the ambassador list

Comment: thanks to your help of course ;) or I would still be stuck?

Comment: Ok - I had a few comments about the ambassador list - but deleted them b/c I saw where it was getting populated in the constructor. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Yes i had to make myself owner and ambassador because only ambassadors can buy in first? Based on this code does tham mean if the ambassador buy in is met- contract is automatically open for everyone?

Comment: I don't think so. `ambassadorOnly` only gets set to `false` in what looks like unreachable code - the else of `if(ambassadorOnly)` in the `antiEarlyWhale`. Looks like there is commented out code that would set `ambassadorOnly` to true after a certain amount of time.